# I was to get a list of my Kubernetes namespace based on a particular label

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am writing a bash script and I need the kubectl command to get all the namespace in my cluster based on a particular label.

```
kubectl get ns -l=app=backend
```

When I run the command above I get:
`no resources found`

Comment: That strongly suggests that no namespaces have that label. If you believe that some exist, can you update your question to include the output of `kubectl get ns <name> -o yaml` for one of those namespaces?

Comment: You're right, the ns, doesn't have that label.

Comment: only the pods in the ns have that label. wondering if there's a way I can manipulate kubectl to output only the ns of the pods that have that label.

Comment: Can you list all your namespaces with labels? Add the output of: `kubectl get ns --show-labels` .  Your command should work, something else must be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only the pods in the ns have that label. wondering if there's a way I can manipulate kubectl to output only the ns of the pods that have that label

You can combine a few commands to do something like:

```
kubectl get pods -A -l app=backend  -o json |
  jq -r '.items[]|.metadata.namespace' |
  sort -u
```

This gets a list of all pods in all namespaces that match the label selector; uses `jq` to extract the namespace name from each pod, and then uses `sort -u` to produce a unique list.

---

You can actually do this without `jq` by using the `go-template` output format, but for me that always means visiting the go template documentation:

```
kubectl get pods -A -l app=backend \
  -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{.metadata.namespace}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' |
  sort -u
```